# makes sticker div stop just above the footer on scroll - document.outerHeight give wrong results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## css

```
.stick{position: fixed !important;}
```

## sticker div with id="summary-div"

```
<div class="col-sm-8"><!-- this Div has 4 accordions div--></div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div>
        <div>
             <div>
                  <div id="order_summary">
                       <div id="summary-div"></div>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## footer

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="stickEndPlace"></div>
```

The below jquery code is making it stick and unstick but the stickermax which is calculated dynamically to determine the css property top to stick it or unstick right above footer. BUT, the problem is; I have to give some static values for some of the scenarios for the "stickermax" variable to be pretty fit above footer otherwise, it is coming sometimes little below or little above the footer having id of "stickEndPlace". Please, help. Thanks

```
    var s = $("#summary-div");
    var pos = s.position();
    var stickermax = $(window).outerHeight() - $("#stickEndPlace").outerHeight() - s.outerHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (windowpos >= pos.top && windowpos < stickermax) {
                $("#summary-div").addClass("stick"); //stick it
                $("#summary-div").css("top",""); //kill top css property which sets while unsticking
            } else if (windowpos >= stickermax) {
                $("#summary-div").removeClass("stick"); //un-stick
                $("#summary-div").css({top: stickermax + "px"}); //set sticker right above the footer
            } else {
               $("#summary-div").removeClass("stick"); //top of page
           }
  });
```

## problem

The actual problem coming is from this line of code.

```
var stickermax = $(window).outerHeight() - $("#stickEndPlace").outerHeight() - s.outerHeight();
```

This "stickermax" value is not coming correctly so the Scroll Div sometimes go below inside footer and sometimes stops above footer.
How to fix that "stickermax" because it is the dynamic "top" css property which is making the sticker DIV positioning.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I'm not sure why you're comparing `window.scrollTop` to stickermax. If you want to make sure the sticky div doesn't overlap the footer, you'd want to compare the sticky div's bottom to the footer's top, right?

Comment: This plugins maybe can help you [stickyElementJS](https://github.com/enmanuelduran/stickyElement.js) or [stickyJs](https://github.com/garand/sticky)